# ArrayList duplicates the values instead of adding new

Tags: java, android, arraylist

My problem is kina weird. I'm making a app for finding different rooms in a school. I want to save the five most recent searches in an ArrayList and display them accordingly.

What keeps happening is that my ArrayList is supposed to add the latest search made to the ArrayList. But what it keeps on doing is to add the lastest search to all the positions that had values.

[This is how is looks but is not how I want it, obviously!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEmz0.png)

This is the method that adds the searches made.

```
public void addPreviousSearch(String[] searchInput, int[] dotPosition) {
    String mapDir = searchInput[0] + ":" + searchInput[2] + ".png";
    Search temp = new Search(searchInput, dotPosition, mapDir);
    Log.d("PREV", mapDir + " " + searchInput[2]);

    previousSearchList.add(0,temp);

    for (Search s : previousSearchList) {
        Log.d("PREV", s.getSearchQuery());
    }

    if (previousSearchList.size() > 5) {
        Log.d("EVAL", previousSearchList.remove(5).toString());
    }
}
```

This is my class that the ArrayList contains.

```
public class Search {
private String[] search;
private int[] dotPosition;
private String mapDicrectory;

public Search(String[] search, int[] dotPosition,String mapDirectory) {
    this.search = search;
    this.dotPosition = dotPosition;
    this.mapDicrectory = mapDirectory;
}

public String[] getSearch() {
    return search;
}

public int[] getDotPosition() {
    return dotPosition;
}

public String getMapDirectory() {
    return mapDicrectory;
}

/**
 * Returns a string formated to display the seach
 * @return String with suitable format
 */
public String getSearchQuery(){
    if(search!=null)
        return search[0] + ":" + search[1] + search[2] + search[3];
    else
        return " ";
}
```

I'd appreciate any input!

Cheers!

UPDATE: To clarify, the ArrayList shows the right number the first time and the remaining four are blank. On second search ArrayList show right number but changes the previous number to be the same as the new one.

UPDATE II: Got it to work by creating a new String[] on each search!

Comment: How do you call `addPreviousSearch` method?

Comment: You are probably using the same searchInput array in all your Search objects...

Comment: The Method is called as soon as the user makes a search. I've even tried using an regular Array but it still changes all the buttons!

Comment: `String[]` is a reference type. If you create all your `Search` objects using the same `String[]` object and alter it at one place, it's going to change at all other places as well.

Comment: THANK YOU Eugen!!
I never thought of it like that. Didn't view String[] as a reference type. I changed so that on every search i create a new String[] and now it works! Thank you!